# How to pad a number with leading zeroes using No javascript framework version in SPFx webpart?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-framework, typescript, pnp-js-core

As I am new to Sharepoint Framework, I am trying to generate request ID for the request form using the pad function for adding leading laeding zeroes using No javascript framework version in SPFx webpart...

Please suggest me any workaround for this...

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  let requestId="123456789";
  console.log(requestId.padStart("12","0"))    
</script>
```

You could use your way to generate request ID,this is a simple demo.

Document for your reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart

Comment: If my reply is helpful to you, you could mark it as an answer and vote it.Thank you.